# Radiobutton requires clicking twice when databound

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm trying to figure out why my radiobuttons act differently once I add a very simple databinding to them.

Consider a super simple form with just two radiobuttons X and Y. Now say I want to persist them, so in the form designer I add a new settings key for the `Checked` property for both X and Y.
Now I run the program. Neither checkbox is initially checked, so I click on X and it becomes checked. So far so good. Now I click Y, and expect X to become unchecked again and Y to become checked, but what happens is that only X gets unchecked, and Y remains so. Clicking Y again then checks Y.

The bindings look as follows:

```
this.rbX.DataBindings.Add("Checked", global::rb.Properties.Settings.Default, "X", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
this.rbY.DataBindings.Add("Checked", global::rb.Properties.Settings.Default, "Y", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Put yours radiobuttons into [Group box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.forms.groupbox.aspx)

Comment: Makes no difference, they're on the same container control (the form) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I had this problem and didn't see a satisfactory answer so... what I learned was that the settings need to be handled "manually" in this case, rather than binding them.

My solution was to add a line of code in the "CheckedChanged" event handler, and also apply the settings on form load.

```
    Properties.Settings.Default.radio_checked_setting = radio.Checked;
```

and

```
radio.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.radio_checked_setting;
```

Seems like a bug to me, but I don't know if it fits the technical definition. Still a huge convenience compared to manually saving all the user settings :)

Answer (score 0):

In the click event:

```
private void RadioButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var rb = sender as RadioButton;
    if (rb != null && !rb.Checked)
    {
        rb.Checked = !rb.Checked;
    }
}
```